# player movement in unity VR oculus

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

After updating to the newest updates of oculus software, and upgrading the oculus integration in unity, the player cant rotate by the right controlller, it can only move by the left controller in any direction, please help, i cant fix this problem

Comment: The best answer you can get to this question is "There is probably something wrong with your code" or "Something changed when you did the update, so you have to change the code accordingly". This is not an appropriate question for this forum, [please read through this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for better success in the future. :)

Comment: yes you are right, i checked out my code, and I found that i change something really important inside the main code.